# deserialising XML correctly into classes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I've managed to easily generate an XML file from a few classes, as shown below;

```
public class AllConfig : XMLEncapsulator
{
    [XmlElement("Database-Settings")]
    public DataBaseConfiguration databaseConfiguration { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Merlin-Settings")]
    public MerlinConfiguration merlinConfiguration { get; set; }
}



public class DataBaseConfiguration : XMLEncapsulator
{
    public string dbIP { get; set; }
    public int ?port { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}

public class MerlinConfiguration : XMLEncapsulator
{
    public string MerlinIP { get; set; }
    public int ?MerlinPort { get; set; }
    public int ?RecievingPort { get; set; }
}


// load classes with information, then;

  try
        {
            allConfig.databaseConfiguration = dbConfig;
            allConfig.merlinConfiguration = merlinConfig;
            allConfig.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception ErrorFinalisingSave)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ErrorFinalisingSave.Message + "3");
        }
```

This works perfectly and gives me:

```
<AllConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <databaseConfiguration>
 <dbIP></dbIP>
 <port></port>
 <username></username>
 <password></password>
</databaseConfiguration>
<merlinConfiguration>
 <MerlinIP></MerlinIP>
 <MerlinPort></MerlinPort>
 <RecievingPort></RecievingPort>
 </merlinConfiguration>
</AllConfig>
```

However, how do i go about retrieving this back into my forms? so i've got something like this, but i can't seem to get it to work;

```
  AllConfig allConfig;
    DataBaseConfiguration dbConfig;
    MerlinConfiguration merlinConfig;

  //need to load here.

//check if values loaded are null, and then load them if they exist into textboxes and such.
```

should i load the two config classes and then assign them to the overall config class? or do i need to load the overall class and assign the sub-config classes off this, like so;

```
 allConfig = new AllConfig();

                dbConfig = new DataBaseConfiguration();
                merlinConfig = new MerlinConfiguration();

                allConfig.databaseConfiguration = dbConfig;
                allConfig.merlinConfiguration = merlinConfig;

                allConfig.databaseConfiguration.Load();
                allConfig.merlinConfiguration.Load();
```

edit: heres my loading method;

```
 public virtual void Load()
{
    if (File.Exists(DeviceManager.path))
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(DeviceManager.path);
        XmlTextReader xr = new XmlTextReader(sr);
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
        object c;
        if (xs.CanDeserialize(xr))
        {
            c = xs.Deserialize(xr);
            Type t = this.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
            {
                p.SetValue(this, p.GetValue(c, null), null);
            }
        }
        xr.Close();
        sr.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how do you deserialize XML into your object?

Comment: i guess so, yeah. edit: i already have the .load() for loading, i just don't know what order to load them in and such. does that make sense?

Comment: What is `XMLEncapsulator`?  Please show us the code you're using to serialize the object.  It doesn't look like you're using the XmlSerializer directly.  Otherwise, the resulting xml would have `Database-Settings` and `Merlin-Settings` as elements.

Comment: @harlam357 see my last edit : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my own problem guys. It was how i was loading it, in the end i ended up doing it like so;

```
allConfig = new AllConfig();
                dbConfig = new DataBaseConfiguration();
                merlinConfig = new MerlinConfiguration();
                allConfig.databaseConfiguration = dbConfig;
                allConfig.merlinConfiguration = merlinConfig;
                allConfig.Load();
```

so i created an instance of the class i serialise, then created the classes which is consists off, and assigned these to the main class. Then i loaded the main class (which i assume through the serializer populates the classes it consists off, and then i accessed them like so;

```
allConfig.databaseConfiguration.port;
allConfig.databaseConfiguration.username;
```

and so on. thanks for the advice though guys, really helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic method used to Deserialize an object from Xml. Does this help?

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml) where T : class, new()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("xml");
    }

    return (T)Deserialize(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)));
}

public static T Deserialize<T>(Stream xmlStream) where T : class, new()
{
    if (xmlStream == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("xmlStream");
    }

    return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlStream);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are save your class with `allConfig.Save();` and try load with

```
allConfig.databaseConfiguration.Load();
allConfig.merlinConfiguration.Load();
```

Looks like you are not use `XmlSerializer` properly.
So try this:

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name;
  public int Age;
}

p.Name = "Stacey"; p.Age = 30;

//serialize
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer (typeof (Person));

using (Stream s = File.Create ("person.xml"))
  xs.Serialize (s, p);

//deserialize
Person p2;
using (Stream s = File.OpenRead ("person.xml"))
  p2 = (Person) xs.Deserialize (s);

Console.WriteLine (p2.Name + " " + p2.Age);   // Stacey 30
```

[C# in Nutshell](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/cs4ch16.aspx)

UPDATE:
Here I adopt example to your code. I remove XmlEncapsulator because I think it's implement Save and Load methods, which not really need. If you really need it, you can return it. Don't think something may change;
So, here code:

```
         AllConfig all = new AllConfig();
         all.databaseConfiguration = new DataBaseConfiguration();
         all.databaseConfiguration.dbIP = "123";
         all.databaseConfiguration.password = "asd";
         all.databaseConfiguration.port = 123;
         all.databaseConfiguration.username = "sad";
         all.merlinConfiguration = new MerlinConfiguration();
         all.merlinConfiguration.MerlinIP = "123";
         all.merlinConfiguration.MerlinPort = 123;
         all.merlinConfiguration.RecievingPort = 123;

        //serialize 
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AllConfig));
        using (Stream s = File.Create ("config.xml"))
            xs.Serialize (s, all); 
        //deserialize 
        AllConfig all2;  
        using (Stream s = File.OpenRead ("config.xml"))
            all2 = (AllConfig)xs.Deserialize(s);
        Console.WriteLine(all2.ToString());
```

Comment: the first bit looked a good idea, but sadly didn't work. i'll try having a look to see why..

Comment: i still can't get it working. from the way i serialize it, i create an overall config, and the two sub configs, assign the sub configs to the overall config and serialize the overall one..but i dunno how to get it back this way.. edit: may have just fixed it.

Comment: thanks for the help : ) i used some of it from your original answer to help me. Check out my solution in my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would implement it using your data types.  As others have said, I would simply remove the `XMLEncapsulator` that you're deriving your data types from.  Also, note that in the resulting xml the `XmlElement` attributes you've specified are now being respected.

```
public void Test()
{
   var dbConfig = new DataBaseConfiguration();
   dbConfig.dbIP = "127.0.0.1";
   dbConfig.port = 12345;
   dbConfig.username = "harlam357";
   dbConfig.password = "password";
   var merlinConfig = new MerlinConfiguration();
   merlinConfig.MerlinIP = "192.168.0.1";
   merlinConfig.MerlinPort = 8080;
   merlinConfig.RecievingPort = 8081;
   var config = new AllConfig { databaseConfiguration = dbConfig, merlinConfiguration = merlinConfig };

   string xml = Serialize(config);
   var config2 = Deserialize<AllConfig>(xml);

   Debug.Assert(config2.databaseConfiguration.dbIP == "127.0.0.1");
   Debug.Assert(config2.databaseConfiguration.port == 12345);
   Debug.Assert(config2.databaseConfiguration.username == "harlam357");
   Debug.Assert(config2.databaseConfiguration.password == "password");
   Debug.Assert(config2.merlinConfiguration.MerlinIP == "192.168.0.1");
   Debug.Assert(config2.merlinConfiguration.MerlinPort == 8080);
   Debug.Assert(config2.merlinConfiguration.RecievingPort == 8081);
}

public static string Serialize<T>(T value) where T : class
{
   if (value == null) return null; // throw or whatever fits your use case

   var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
   using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
   {
      xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, value);
      return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.GetBuffer());
   }
}

public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml) where T : class
{
   if (xml == null) return null; // throw or whatever fits your use case

   var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
   using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)))
   {
      return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream);
   }
}
```

Resulting XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AllConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Database-Settings>
    <dbIP>127.0.0.1</dbIP>
    <port>12345</port>
    <username>harlam357</username>
    <password>password</password>
  </Database-Settings>
  <Merlin-Settings>
    <MerlinIP>192.168.0.1</MerlinIP>
    <MerlinPort>8080</MerlinPort>
    <RecievingPort>8081</RecievingPort>
  </Merlin-Settings>
</AllConfig>
```

Comment: thanks for your input : ) it was only the deserializing i was stuck on, but i've fixed that now!